# How do I identify the issue if no error message is outputted when trying to tokenize text in a dataframe column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nltk, tokenize

I am trying to tokenize text in a single column of a dataframe but the code does not run to completion or output an error message. The hourglass icon in Jupyter Notebook is present after more than an hour. The csv file loaded into Jupyter notebooks is about 54 MB. I have tried other word tokenization techniques with the same issue. The code runs without the ".sum()" but that is still needed to complete the tokenization. Is there a way to identify the issue without an error message being received? Any help is appreciated. Below is the code:

```
import nltk
import pandas as pd
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
import string
import re

data = pd.read_csv('file.csv',encoding='ISO-8859-1')
data['column'] = data['column'].astype(str)

def my_tokenizer(text):
    return text.split() if text != None else []
tokens = data['column'].map(my_tokenizer).sum()
```

Comment: One idea: run your code on a small subset of your data (e.g., run it on `data_100 = data.sample(100)` or `data_100 = data.head(100)`). If execution finishes, re-run on progressively larger subsets to get a sense of how long the full dataset would take.

Comment: @PeterLeimbigler thank you. I actually just tired this as I received your comment and it worked on a much smaller dataset so it very well could be just the dataset size which now  I need to find a way on how to run the code on chunks of the dataset and append, I think.